# Is there an open-source VSTi of WebAudio-based synth/instrument/effect?

Tags: open-source, web-audio-api, vst

I want to explore the available options for building a VSTi for instruments built on the Web Audio API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really - you would need to build a custom Web Audio engine host, since a VSTi would need to be able to pipe the output of the Web Audio instrument out through the VSTi interface.  No one has done this, to my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for dropping a line, Chris. Such a project would make Web Audio so much more popular. Do you think there is someone from the Chromium project I could ask for help on this?

Comment: I've tried editing your answer into something that I can mark as such - "No, there isn't such a project, yet" or something similar. My edit was not accepted... Anyways, I can't mark a comment for an answer, so would you please, edit it yourself. Thanks.